# Maintain resolution of image after binarisation and median filtering

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a set of images that have been binarised (adaptive threshold) followed by application of median filter. The source images are in jpg format, and after the application of above mentioned steps, the images are saved in png format. 
The problem is that the images have originally 200*200 ppi resolution but after the above mentioned processing steps, resolution decreases to 72*72 ppi( due to increase in print size). I want to maintain the resolution of the image.Can someone please help me with this?
Also please note that I tried saving the original images in png format without any processing steps, then also the resolution decreased.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably you'll need to use a `png` library (and maybe jpeg library to read the original ppi) directly since openCV doesnt give such options afaik.

Comment: The dpi/ppi is not really very relevant during processing, if your image is 4,000 pixels by 3,000 pixels at the start of image processing and still 4,000x3,000 at the end, you have not lost any quality even if some imaginary printer you are not even using now thinks the image would fit on a smaller piece of paper.